# Setting Active File as First Tab

Tags: eclipse

So, I am using Eclipse version 4.2.2. I, like many programmers, often have many files open at once. I find that Eclipse is kind of wonky when it comes to which tabs(representing open files) will be displayed at the top of the IDE and which you will have to access by clicking the arrow that creates a dropdown showing other open files. Sometimes selecting a file will leave it in the upper tab, sometimes it will not, making me have to hunt for the file to open it.

What I would like, is for an active file to be put in the front of the line in the tabs, and each file subsequently selected would push the front down one and take its place, like a queue data structure.

I imagine the above is not likely, but thought I would ask. I'm aware that there is a back button that can take you to the previous file but I find it doesn't help when I am jumping between 5 or 6 files in no particular order e.g file 1 to file 4 to file 5 to file 2.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do what I am asking? I've looked through the docs and did some searching but didn't find anything particularly useful in this regard. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Install [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/). It will automatically hide every editor which you don't actively work with.